# django form widget checkboxselectmultiple how to render User.last_name

Tags: django, forms, checkbox, widget

Rookie in Django/Python. I'm using a django form for selecting among users.
First a queryset filters according to group__name, then the form generate HTML with a checkbox widget. It's basic and well working.
I want HTML displaying 'User.last_name User.email'. Not only 'User.username' aside the checkbox.
Is it possible (and easy) to change this widget's default behaviour?

```
# model is User
# forms
class SelMembersForm(forms.Form):

    qs = User.objects.filter(groups__name='any_group_name')
    picked = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(qs, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

# views
def members_select(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SelMembersForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            picked = form.cleaned_data.get('picked')

    else:
        form = SelMembersForm

    return render_to_response('staff/selmembers.html', {'form':form },
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))


# template
<form method='post'> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have implemented similar issue, hope this works for you.

First I made two methods in forms.py:

```
def appended_list(items, item):
    items.append(item)
    return items


def inserted_list(items, index, item):
   items.insert(index, item)
   return items
```

now I show the list by this:

```
 picked= forms.ChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.SelectMultiple( initial=1, choices=inserted_list([(x.id,  x.username+": "+x.first_name+" "+x.last_name) for x in User.objects.all()], 0, ('0', ' --')),label="PICKED")
```

Comment: I have the same problem. can you please [take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57884248/render-a-checkboxselectmultiple-form-using-the-data-present-in-database-initia)